# Помогите border radius animation

Tags: css

Подскажите как в:

```
@keyframes switchSize {
   100% {
}}
```

Задать изменение `border-radius` у вызываемого элемента?
А именно :

```
.class1{
    -webkit-animation: rotate 6s linear infinite,switchSize 1s infinite !important;
    animation: rotate 6s linear infinite,switchSize 1s infinite !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, какую именно анимацию нужно получить. Вот как вариант.
Значения можно поставить свои.

```css
.class1 {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 6s linear infinite,switchSize 1s infinite !important;
    animation: rotate 6s linear infinite,switchSize 1s infinite !important;
}


@keyframes switchSize {
  50% {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">123</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z5kav1oL